# javascript determine if my variable is null

Tags: javascript

```
$(function () {
    //To send data from input text
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var gender = $('#gender').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var illness = $('#illness').val();
        var selectunit = $('#selectunit').val();

        if (typeof name !== null) {
            my codes here...
        } else {
            alert('Some fields are missing!');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

i want to trap my variables (name,age,address,illness) not to be null before doing the codes
please help thanks

Comment: just check if variable is empty? if (name != "" && gender != "" ...)

Comment: use a validation plugin like [jQuery validation](jqueryvalidation.org) if possible

Comment: Or even more simply `if (!name)`. `null` and empty strings are both *falsey*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
name != null || name != ""
```

instead of

```
typeof name !== null
```

if your case is to check if name is undefined then use

```
typeof name !== "undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null like so:

```
if (somevariable == null) { /* code */ }
```

The check for `undefined` is a little different:

```
if (typeof somevariable === "undefined") { /* code */ }
```